# How to use Django Filter with Arrayfield

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Is it possible to use django-filter BaseInFilter with with django ArrayField?

Here is a sample of what I am trying to do;

```
models.py

class Stays(models.Model):
   best_describes_house = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True),
        default=list,
    )
```

```
filterset.py

class ItemInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):

    pass

class StayFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    best_describes_house__in = ItemInFilter(
        field_name="best_describes_house", lookup_expr="in"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Stays
        fields = [
            "best_describes_house__in",
        ]
```

I am trying to make a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/stays/best_describes_house__in=villa,lake`. I keep getting;

> operator does not exist: character varying[] = text[]
> LINE 1: ...ays" WHERE "lodging_stays"."best_describes_house" IN (ARRAY[...

Am I doing something wrong?

I have also tried doing this using `IntegerField` as stated from this example in the documentation - [BaseInFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#baseinfilter), and it works fine

Comment: Please *don't* use an `ArrayField`. Relational databases still do not handle arrays effectively: use a model with a `ForeignKey` to this model.

Comment: The field is like a tag. I don't think `ForeignKey` is an effective way of doing this, since if I have 30 tags, I have to send a post request for each one of them.

Comment: why? You can make a subserializer (for example a `SlugRelatedField` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield ) to make a POST request and store all data. You should *not* model data in terms of views.